# Enabling AirPlay for IOS application

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

Hi I am developing IOS application in which I am showing HLS videos in my application. I want to enable Airplay option for my application.
I tried it in following way :

```
 _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                 initWithContentURL:url];
[_moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
```

But it is not showing Airplay option for my application. I checked it once I start playing video (my player appears on screen) in my setting AirPlay option is not coming up.
Is there any other setting needed. Need Some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sender and receiver and also same WIFI network then AirPlay is display on iPhone of your screen to access the Control Center. otherwise the AirPlay symbol is not display on Control Center.

**To use AirPlay, you need these:**

```
   1. iPhone 4 (or later), iPad, iPad mini, or iPod touch (4th generation or later)
   2. For videos or photos: Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation)
   3. For music: Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation), AirPort Express, or AirPlay-enabled speakers or receivers
```

**Use AirPlay**

```
1. Connect your iOS device and Apple TV or AirPort Express to the same Wi-Fi network.
2. Swipe up from the bottom of your screen to access Control Center.
3. Tap AirPlay.
```

**SNEDER :** iPhone 4 (or later), iPad, iPad mini, or iPod touch (4th generation or later)

**RECEIVERS :** Apple TV (2nd or 3rd generation), AirPort Express, or AirPlay-enabled speakers or receivers

Note : SNEDER and RECEIVERS to the same Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Hi kirti thank you for quick replay. I am asking about how to enable airplay option for my application not asking about what all other requirements. For some other application it shows that option in settings.

Comment: But for some other application it showing airplay option in setting even though there is not receiver.

Comment: you code is correct, but the symbol is display when you have RECEIVERS with same network.

Comment: Not Possible please which APP.

Comment: GoCoder application. So once you start application it will show you airplay option in settings.

Comment: only Airdrop is display on Control Center.

Comment: Is there any other requirement in terms of code for enabling airplay or whatever I did that is sufficient?

Comment: Yeah same application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68386/discussion-between-nilkash-and-kirit-modi).